# Android sidecroller template

Tags: 2d, java, android, side-scroller

I want to create a sidescroller game for Android but it seems stupid to reinvent the wheel and since there are a lot of android sidescroller games already out I though that there must be some sort of template or something so I can get started quicker, so I can keep developing from there.

Answer (score 4):

There is [Replica Island by Chris Pruett](http://replicaisland.blogspot.com/). The game is open-source, and his blog takes you through the entire development as he works on the game, and solved issues that pop up. Definitely worth the read.